# Paradigm for Internally Swapping Child Type

Tags: c++, inheritance, types, polymorphism, siblings

Let's say that I have this:

```
struct Base {
    virtual void swap();
    Expensive mem;
};

struct Left : Base {
    void swap() override;
};

struct Right : Base {
    void swap() override;
};
```

Given a `vector<shared_ptr<Base>> foo` which contains `Left` and `Right` objects. Lets say element 13 was a `Left` now I want it to be a `Right`. I can do something like:

```
foo[13] = make_shared<Right>();
```

But now let's suppose that `Expensive` is very costly to construct or copy, and let's suppose that `Left` and `Right` contain no members of their own, they are simply a different way of manipulating and interpreting `mem`. Is there a way that I can cast or tell element 13 that it is now a `Right` without destroying the `Left` that was there? Could I use `enable_shared_from_this` or similar to manipulate the destruction and reconstruction to where I could call `foo[13].swap()` and it would "become" a `Right`?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could consider making `Left` and `Right` the same type. But if you can't do that, then you can still take advantage of move semantics. Assume `Expensive` is cheaply movable. Then you could do something like this:

```
struct Base {
    Base(Expensive mem) : mem(std::move(mem)) {}
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Base> swap() = 0;
    Expensive mem;
};
struct Left : Base {
    Left(Expensive mem) : Base(std::move(mem)) {}
    std::shared_ptr<Base> swap() override;
};
struct Right : Base {
    Right(Expensive mem) : Base(std::move(mem)) {}
    std::shared_ptr<Base> swap() override;
};
std::shared_ptr<Base> Left::swap() {
    return std::make_shared<Right>(std::move(mem));
}
std::shared_ptr<Base> Right::swap() {
    return std::make_shared<Left>(std::move(mem));
}
// ...
foo[13] = foo[13]->swap();
```

(Note that destruction of the original object pointed to by `foo[13]` doesn't occur until the body of `std::shared_ptr<Base>::operator=` is entered, by which time `swap()` will have completed and left `mem` in a destructible state, so it seems to me that this code would be well-defined).